# How come this greedy algorithm does not compute the correct amount of coins?

Tags: javascript, html

For some inputted values, my function computes the correct amount of coins. But for most, it's completely off. My code seems simple, but I'm still confused on what's causing the multiple errors. Below is the JavaScript code, but this is the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/decereqeva/edit?html,css,js,output) for the entire project (html, css, and javascript).

```
function calculateCents(){
    var amount = document.getElementById("centsInput").value;

    var numberOfQuarters = 0
    while (amount >= 0.25) {
        numberOfQuarters++;
        amount = amount - numberOfQuarters * 0.25;
    } 

    var numberOfDimes = 0
    while (amount >= 0.1) {
        numberOfDimes++;
        amount = amount - numberOfDimes * 0.1;
    } 

    var numberOfNickels = 0
    while (amount >= 0.05) {
        numberOfNickels++;
        amount = amount - numberOfNickels * 0.05;
    } 

    var numberOfPennies = 0
    while (amount >= 0.01) {
        numberOfPennies++;
        amount = amount - numberOfPennies * 0.1;
    } 



    document.write(
    `It takes ` + numberOfQuarters + ` quarters, ` + numberOfDimes + ` dimes, ` + numberOfNickels + ` nickels, and ` + numberOfPennies + ` pennies.`
    );
}
```

Comment: Which values have a correct output and which values have the wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at the following snippet

```
    while (amount >= 0.25) {
        numberOfQuarters++;
        amount = amount - numberOfQuarters * 0.25;
    }
```

Lets say amount is $2. In the first iteration you will increase `numberOfQuarters` by one so numberOfQuarters = 1 and then subtract `1 * 0.25` from amount, resulting in amount = 1.75.

in the next iteration, numberOfQuarters = 2, and then you will subtract `2 * 0.25` from amount resulting in amount = 1.25, which is wrong.

I guess this should be enough to point you in right direction.

Comment: In other words, you're not subtracting _a quarter_ on each iteration, you're subtracting _all of the quarters counted so far_ on each iteration.

Comment: Not sure how this flew over my head after 2 hours of looking at my code. It seems so obvious now that you say it. Thanks!